# Как исправить ошибки, возникающие после добавления новой страницы XAML Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1

Я добавляю новую XAML страницу правой кнопкой по приложению в дереве проектов - дальше жму добавить, дальше создать элемент и выбираю пустая страница XAML. Называю допустим HomePage.xaml и создаю. После чего компилятор выдает следующие ошибки:

> Ошибка    CS1061  'App" не содержит определения для "InitializeComponent" и не удалось найти метод расширения "InitializeComponent", принимающий тип "App" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).
>   Ошибка  CS1061  'HomePage" не содержит определения для "InitializeComponent" и не удалось найти метод расширения "InitializeComponent", принимающий тип "HomePage" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).
>   Ошибка  CS1061  'MainPage" не содержит определения для "InitializeComponent" и не удалось найти метод расширения "InitializeComponent", принимающий тип "MainPage" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).
>   Ошибка  CS0103  Имя "Login_Button" не существует в текущем контексте.
>   Ошибка  CS0103  Имя "Login_Input" не существует в текущем контексте.
>   Ошибка  CS0103  Имя "Password_Input" не существует в текущем контексте.

При этом когда страница была одна(MainPage), то никаких ошибок не было.

Кнопки логина и инпуты используются в событии клика следующим образом:

```
private async void Login_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Login_Button.IsEnabled = false;

    string login = Login_Input.Text;
    string password = Password_Input.Password;
```

Эти строки подчеркнуты красным. Помогите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А если попробовать переоткрыть Студию и сделать ребилд, ошибки сохраняются?

Comment: Сделал как Вы сказали, проблема действительно ушла! Спасибо Вам за подсказку.